# awk to extract partial match to pattern and exact match on same lines

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract a partial pattern and and exact match using `awk`. The partial pattern is `gene analysis,` and the exact match is `common variant`. Line 1 is extracted because it has both of these criteria. Line 4 is not because it does not contain the exact match.  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '$2 ~ /^gene analysis,("common variant")$/' file
```

**file** `tab-delimeted`

```
123 this is for gene analysis, common variant
456 xxxx
789 yyyy
111 gene analysis, deletion
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
123 this is for gene analysis, common variant
```

Comment: elaborate your **partial pattern**. Should this  `123 this is for  common variant, main analysis` be matched?

Comment: no it should not be matched.... the `common variant` should be an exact match. The partial match is `gene analysis,` as this phase may be in multiple lines but only `gene analysis, common variant` is extracted. Does that help and thank you :).

Comment: and why do you call it partial as it considers only `gene analysis, common variant` but not `some analysis, common variant`?

Comment: define "partial-match", does it mean either word of "gene analysis"?  If not, how is this different than matching both "gene analysis" and "common variant"?

Comment: Maybe partial is not the correct word to use. Since the text in front of `gene analysis,` could be different an exact match for that can not be used but maybe the pattern or partial match could. Additionally, what follows `gene analysis` must be an exact match to `common variant`.. anything else is not a match. Thank you :).

Comment: My understanding is you're looking for an exact match of `gene analysis, common variant` string, there is no need to split the string.

Comment: `Since the text in front of gene analysis, could be different an exact match for that can not be used` - still struggling to figure out what you mean by that and in what way `gene analysis` is different from `common variant` and why split the 4 words like that instead of `gene` vs `analysis, common variant` or some other combination. I don't think I'm alone in being confused - you might want to [edit] your question to clarify and provide examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you're looking for an exact match of "gene analysis, common variant" string, there is no need to split the string for matching parts

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $2~/gene analysis, common variant$/' file
```